# CefSharp ScreenshotAsync does not always return the correct bitmap

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I'm having trouble capturing every frame of an animation using a CefSharp bounded object. It appears the bitmap returned by `Browser.ScreenshotAsync` is not always correctly synchronized.  This is my javascript render function which moves a WebGL object horizontally at a constant rate:

```
function animate() {
    object.position.x -= 100; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    cefBountObject('animate()');
}
```

This is my CEF bounded object:

```
public void cefBountObject(string callback) {
    Browser.ScreenshotAsync().ContinueWith((task) => {
        task.Result.Save(string.Format("{0:D4}.png", frameNumber++));
        Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(callback);
    });
}
```

This does save every file in the sequence without skips: 0000.png, 0001.png, 0002.png, etc. However, some image files are repeats and some image files jump a frame. I think I am encountering an unsynchronized threading issue but I don't see where that might be. In fact, if I put a  breakpoint on the last line `Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(callback);` and step through the animation, all the files are generated in sequence correctly.